# Eclipse Hover over variables in debug not showing contents

Tags: eclipse, debugging

At a break point my Eclipse used to show me the value of a hovered variable, now it only shows the type name.

How can I turn that back on?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a setting but something wrong with your config.  Does this happen everywhere?  Post an example project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the preferences and type "Hovers" in the search box at the top. Make sure the Combined one is checked.  Though I have found that even if they are set correctly sometimes (in the case of certain fields) it shows only the type, not sure why that's the case. You might want to ask about that in the Eclipse JDT newsgroup.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like Ubuntu can intercept some of the Special Key presses.